# When you instantiate a subclass from a DLL, is the vtable correct?

Tags: c++, windows, dll, dynamic-library

When you have a base class in your main executable and subclasses (say, plugins) defined in DLLs, what happens when you want to get a plugin?

I am looking for an article/answer that'd clarify what happens when you

- load a DLL
- call a DLL's function that returns a `plugin*` (it has virtual functions)
- use that plugin in your main executable's code
- delete, unload

I am thinking about the vtable and other C++ issues. For instance, if you unload the DLL stil having some plugins running... The "code" will be gone?

Comment: Yes, the vtable is correct, even if you derive from a class defined in a .dll and overload virtual functions.  Why do you suspect it wouldn't be?

Comment: Do you load that DLL  explicitely using LoadLibrary, or implicitely at program start?

Comment: I used some Boost utils for this. I load the DLL during run time, I pass a string to Boost, I get a function back. I call function to get plugin. But you can also assume I use native APIs. What then? The run-time vs start-up differences might be ineresting

Comment: @CodieCodeMonkey: presumably, the vtable will only be known to be correct if the DLL and the executable were built with the same tools?  There isn't a universal standard, is there?

Comment: @HarryJohnston Good point, although I suppose it's the same problem if you build different object files in the same project with two different compilers that don't agree on the v-table structure.  I don't think that's a .dll problem, just a standards mismatch.

Comment: @CodieCodeMonkey: it's more likely to be a problem for a DLL, and particularly when the DLL is a plugin, because that typically means that the DLL is being built separately to the executable, usually by a different person.  Rather than having to make an effort to wind up with mismatched vtables, as in the statically linked case, you have to make an effort to avoid winding up with (potentially) mismatched vtables.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Agreed.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - just out of curiosity - how do professional projects handle this? How do you release software that is extensible by design (e.g. some music software)? Do the designers of such software have to specify the exact compiler version and flags .. to avoid the above issues? Or is there a better approach to (object-oriented) plugins?

Comment: No idea, sorry, though my impression is that most plugin architectures are not object-oriented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are talking about plugins, you must be doing something like `LoadLibrary`. Assuming Windows:

- Load a library. You would normally call `LoadLibrary` followed by `GetProcAddress`. The DLL is loaded into the process address space and you have the pointer to the function exposed.
- Call a DLL's function that returns a `plugin*` (it has virtual functions). You would cast a the return value from `GetProcAddress` to the function pointer type, and call it. Everything should work as normal.
- Use that plugin in your main executable's code. There is nothing special.
- Delete the plugin. I assume you use a function in the DLL to do so, and it should be fine. Directly calling `delete` can be dangerous, as the DLL may have a separate memory manager (depending on what runtime you use).
- Unload the DLL. You call `FreeLibrary`, and the code is gone. The pointers you previously get from `GetProcAddress` become invalid.

I am not aware specific vtable issues. If you unload the DLL while the code is still running, I would assume the program will crash at this point, as the code address space becomes invalid.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Two things need clarification. **First**, you wrote the pointers become invalid. Do they turn `null` or just become "inappropriate" for further usage? Would the app crash immediately, or after invoking a virtual function on the pointer? Or any function at all? **Second**, you say that for every `new` in the DLL the `delete` should also be there? What if the DLL func returns a `unique_ptr` ? Isthe issue with a separate memory manager a Windows thing only?

Comment: Pointers never become null automatically in the C/C++ world. They just become wild pointers and are dangerous. Crashes are likely. Yes, new/delete in the same DLL is a Windows thing, as there is not a *standard* C runtime in Windows. You probably do not want to use `unique_ptr`, unless you make sure the host and the plugins use the same C runtime (same MSVC version and the /MD option).

Comment: So on Linux you can delete an "external" pointer and be just fine?

Comment: @KalamarObliwy: As far as I know, yes.